# An Inequality Problem with Four variables

Tags: inequality

If $x,y,p,q>0$ are positive numbers, Is there a function f (p, q) containing only p, q that makes the following inequality hold?
$$x^p+y^q>(x+y)^{f(p,q)}?$$
I try to find the minimum value of this function
$$\frac{\log(x^p+y^q)}{\log(x+y)}$$
but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume such a function exists. Letting $x$ tend to $0$ we see that we must have $y^q\ge y^{f(p,q)}$ for all $y>0$. Replacing $y$ by $1/y$ we get also the reverse equality $y^q\le y^{f(p,q)}$. From this we get that $f(p,q)=q$. Interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ we get $f(p,q)=p$
This is a contradiction if $p\ne q$. However, if $p=q$ we get the inequality
$$x^p+y^p>(x+y)^p.$$
But if $p\ge 1$ we have always the reverse inequality $$x^p+y^p\le (x+y)^p$$
As a conclusion, there is no such function $f$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean